# Unable to send Messages by Twilio Api using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, twilio

The Send SMS from Twilio [Subaccounts](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts) (and yes they are globally enabled message number) functionality not working for me.

Here is the code for sending messages

```
 public function notification($loggedUserId,$send_to){
    global $objSession;
    $modelUser = new Application_Model_User();      
    $data = $modelUser->getTwilio('twilio',$loggedUserId);
    // here in $data I got all data about subaccount 
     //by which a user is logged in and array i got is
    /* 
    Array
    (
     [twilio_id] => 1
     [twilio_trainer_id] => 147 (its logged user id)
     [twilio_phone] => +177*****09
     [twilio_sid] => ACfd42**********709***b***********
     [twilio_token] => 88a*************************da**
     [twilio_added] => 2014-04-29 19:42:14
    )*/

    // Step 1: Set Library.
    require_once(ROOT_PATH.'/library/twilio/Services/Twilio.php');
    // Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
    $AccountSid = $data['twilio_sid'];
    $AuthToken = $data['twilio_token'];
    $twilioPhone = $data['twilio_phone'];


    // Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
    // Step 4: make an array of people we know, to send them a message. 
    // Feel free to change/add your own phone number and name here.

    $peopleInfo = $this->objUser->getUserData($send_to); 
    //prd($peopleInfo['user_phone']);

    // Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
    // $name is the name next to it


    if(!empty($peopleInfo['user_phone'])){
        $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
            // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
            // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
            $twilioPhone,
            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            $peopleInfo['user_phone'],
            // the sms body
            "Hey , Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
        );
        // Display a confirmation message on the screen
        echo "Sent Successufully ";
    }
    exit;
}
```

Everything runs fine, but messages are not received on my number.
Sent Successfully is printed, but no messages received.

Can anyone see what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Check logs section in your Twilio account page.

Comment: @usef_ksa  there are no messages in my Twilio logs.

Comment: @usef_ksa check if something goes wrong in the Twilio.php class. after you assign the $client obj

Comment: @dixromos98 : No there is nothing wrong in the Twilio.php
and one more thing the money is being deducted from my account but the messages still not received.

Comment: @Rock Rathore do you add area code to your phone number? e.g. for uk 0044

Comment: @usef_ksa : I am able to see messages in my Twilio logs now but not on my cell phone and by the way money is being deducted from my Twilio account.

Comment: @dixromos98 : Yes i have added the area code +91 that is for India with my phone number.

Comment: @RockRathore is the class handling area codes? i mean does it need a format? for example if you give it 0091 or +91 or 91 does it matter to it? will the class format the final number even if you send in different formats of area code or does it need one format for the area code?

Comment: @RockRathore $client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '456bef', null, null, 3); try sending the msg like the example from Twilio.php

Comment: If you see the message in your Twilio logs, it means it sent. I think the problem is not with your code, it is between Twilio network and your provider. Try to test on another numbers.

Comment: Thanks Guys, as you mentioned there might be a problem with my area code. So I will be going to contact Twilio Support and see what they can come up with.

Comment: @dixromos98 : Please post that message about class handling area codes as answer so I can accept that as best answer.
Thanks Rock Rathore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Requested by Rock Rathore,

Is the class handling area codes? I mean does it need a format? For example if you give it 0091 or +91 or 91 does it matter to it? will the class format the final number even if you send in different formats of area code or does it need one format for the area code?